# web api 2 bad request when accessed the host using ip address

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I'm getting a 400 bad request error when I am accessing an ASP.net self hosted web api 2 via a url that uses the computer name. When I use localhost it works fine.

I know that this can be resolved for IIS hosted site by updating applicationhost.config, but how do i fix it in web-api 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that Web API thinks that you are accessing it from a different domain, which is not allowed by default.

This is called `Cross-origin resource sharing` (`CORS`).

`Web API 2.2` makes it easy to enable `CORS` by providing the `EnableCorsAttribute`.

Basic Usage

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class ResourcesController : ApiController
{
    ...
```

Attribute definition

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public EnableCorsAttribute(
    string origins,
    string headers,
    string methods
)
```

You will also need to install the CORS package from `nuget`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Comment: but if thats the case, error should have been related to CORS `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` or something like that and not `invalid host`